# Turn Off Compressing Cell Background Image - Objective-C (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am adding content to a UITableViewCell using the following code:

```
NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"title"]]];
[[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:[device valueForKey:@"imagename"]] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
```

However, while this code works, it compresses my images to fit into the cell. I want the images to only show the top portion of the image, and not stretch or compress at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UIView setContentMode:]

The modes are as below:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIViewContentMode) {
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
UIViewContentModeTop,
UIViewContentModeBottom,
UIViewContentModeLeft,
UIViewContentModeRight,
UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
UIViewContentModeTopRight,
UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
};
```

You can use topLeft.

**Added:**

The stretchableImage with top cap height will make your image fit to your view. I don't think you can show top part of your image.

If you need to show only top part of your image, try this.

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[device valueForKey:@"imagename"]]];
[iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];
[iv setClipsToBounds:YES];
cell.backgroundView = iv;
```

Change your last line of code to this and try.

Comment: Ok. I'm new to iOS programming. Is this another line of code, or a continuation on my last line?

Comment: Ah you're using stretchableImage. Is it necessary for sure? If so, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No. Not necessary. It was the only thing I knew to put in there to format the image. Can you update with how to add in the UIView code when stretchableImage is removed?

Comment: Added you changed code. The cell's background is blank now. Did this new code need to be applied to the cell's background?

Comment: It is. I added one more line to set the image view as cell's background. My mistake.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly!